# Print Python string with encode('utf-8') gives Execption

Tags: python, exception, printing, console, nonetype

I have a python script that contains the following code to output text to the console: `print('{0}: Title: {1}'.format(var1, var2).encode('utf-8').strip()`

`var2` contains umlauts (e.g., ü, ä, ö).

Interestingly, the text gets printed to the console, but at the same time the following execption occurs:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

What is happening here? Which object has `NoneType`?

Comment: What Python version is this?  Where is your right parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this in Python 3.6.3:

**Put this code in the beginning of your file**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

**Then remove the ".encode("utf-8")" call**

```
print('{0}: Title: {1}'.format(var1, var2)).strip()
```

**Sample Code successfully executed in Python 3.6.3 64bit**

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
var1 = "Hallo"
var2 = "Ölfabrik"
print('{0}: Title: {1}'.format(var1, var2)).strip()
```

**Output**

```
Hallo: Title: Ölfabrik
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: UTF-8 is the [default source encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/) in Python3, so the encoding declaration in the source file is unnecessary.  You seem to be confusing the encoding of the source file with the encoding of the program's output.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing it up.